# EME playready video says source not supported in ie11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video-streaming, html5-video

I am following micro soft EME DEMO  in order to play a encrypted content using Dash format in html 5 video tag. I am using IE 11 browser , unprotected videos are playing fine...but with the protected content videos are failing with MEDIA ERROR 4 (MEDIA_ERR_ SOURCE _NOT_SUPPORTED)... any help....

Comment: Thanks I have a got a solution myself....Graphics driver was missing in my pc and now it starts to play

Comment: If the video is a webm container, you need aditional software http://www.webmproject.org/ie/ But if the video is mp4 You can reproduce with IE11. In this page you have DEMO that use EME: http://www.drmtoday.com/demos